# Text selection overflows in revisions, "Side-by-side Markdown" mode

Tags: bug, design, markdown, revisions-list

When trying to select text in a side-by-side revision, that is, select the text from one side, it works perfectly fine. However, the selection overflows to the other side when using "Side-by-side Markdown".

**Demo:**

[image: Text selection in revisions]

Repro on Chrome v89.0.4389 (64-bit), Windows 10.